# Problem of the ideal in the GNS construction

Tags: quantum-mechanics, mathematical-physics, operators, hilbert-space

I read this in the wikipedia's article about the [GNS construction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfand%E2%80%93Naimark%E2%80%93Segal_construction):

> "the degenerate elements, a in A satisfying ρ(a* a)= 0, form a vector subspace I of A. By a C*-algebraic argument, one can show that I is a left ideal of A (known as the left kernel of ρ)."

Is there a full proof online?
A related quetion: As C* algebras are equipped with a * norm
is the set of X such that $\|X^*X \| = 0$ a "natural" ideal of the C* algebra?

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Answer (score 1):

I had the answer in one of my own books. $\|$
I did not find the answer online but in Haag's book: Local Quantum Physics.
He defines a state over a C* algebra $\mathcal{A}$ as a
normalized positive linear complex form.
Positive means that $f(A^*A) \ge 0$
Having defined the set $\mathcal{I}$ of the X with $f(X^*X) = 0$
we want to show that it is an ideal i.e $f((AX)^* AX)) = 0$.
this is possible with a Schwarz like inequality.
Let us expand the non negative
$$f((tX+Z)^*(tX+Z)) =$$
$$t^2 f(X^*X) + tf(X^*Z + Z^*X) +f(Z^*Z) =$$
$$t^2 f(X^*X) + 2t Re f(Z^*X) +f(Z^*Z)$$
As it is always non negative the discrimibant is null or negarive
$$[Re f(Z^*X))^2 \le f(X*X)  f(Z*Z)$$
If X belongs to I we have $f(X^*X) = 0$ so
$Re f(Z^*X)$ is null.
Let us take $Z = (AX)^*A$
in this case the positivity of f implies that it is a positive or null number. 
This proves that AX belongs to $\mathcal{I}$